# How to get severity information for Business Transaction severity info using AppDynamics REST call

Tags: appdynamics

When I am invoking a REST URI from the browser using an URL like the following

http://:/controller/rest/applications//business-transactions?output=JSON

and this is providing the output as

```
[
    {
    "id": 443,
    "internalName": "/AjaxCapabilities/ResultProvider.aspx",
    "name": "/AjaxCapabilities/ResultProvider.aspx",
    "entryPointType": "ASP_DOTNET",
    "background": false,
    "tierName": "Microsoft Dynamics CRM/AjaxCapabilities",
    "tierId": 24
  },
    {
    "id": 444,
    "internalName": "/AppWebServices/AppGridWebService.ashx",
    "name": "/AppWebServices/AppGridWebService.ashx",
    "entryPointType": "ASP_DOTNET",
    "background": false,
    "tierName": "Microsoft Dynamics CRM",
    "tierId": 25
  },
    {
    "id": 445,
    "internalName": "/{636312148120003543}/WebResources",
    "name": "/{636312148120003543}/WebResources",
    "entryPointType": "ASP_DOTNET",
    "background": false,
    "tierName": "Microsoft Dynamics CRM",
    "tierId": 25
  },...]
```

This output is missing the indicator/field for severity information like WARNING,CRITICAL,NORMAL etc.
How to get the severity information from the AppDynamics REST call ?

Answer (score 1):

Severity is associated with specific events/entities in AppDynamics. Based on your API call I can see that you are trying to retrieve information about Business Transactions (BTs). Severity param is not associated with BTs.

e.g. You can pull Severity for Health rule violations in AppDynamics by making the following API call:
http:///controller/rest/applications//problems/healthrule-violations
Result:

```
<policy-violations><policy-violation>
  <id>266</id>
  <name>CPU utilization is too high</name>
  <startTimeInMillis>1452630655000</startTimeInMillis>
  <detectedTimeInMillis>0</detectedTimeInMillis>
  <endTimeInMillis>1452630715000</endTimeInMillis>
  <incidentStatus>RESOLVED</incidentStatus>
  **<severity>WARNING</severity>**
  <triggeredEntityDefinition>
    <entityType>POLICY</entityType>
    <entityId>30</entityId>
    <name>CPU utilization is too high</name>
  </triggeredEntityDefinition>
....
```

You can find further information about using AppD controller API in the following documentation pages:

https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO42/AppDynamics+APIs

https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO42/Alert+and+Respond+API

Answer (score 0):

You can get severity information by appending &severities=INFO,WARN,ERROR to your URL.

So your url must be like : http://:/controller/rest/applications//business-transactions?output=JSON&severities=INFO,WARN,ERROR

Comment: Hi ,I tried appending &severities=INFO,WARN,ERROR to my URL end ,but the result is the same unfortunately .